# GUI For Loop Button

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, loops

I have multiple channels and I want to display their information on a GUI.
I would like to show the name, the length, the sample rate...etc and having a button to plot it or to modify the gain.

Each channel is independent and it is not always the same number of channels, thus I would like to create a pattern for one channel and display it as many time as there are channels, where for example each channel is underneath the previous one.

It is basically a loop of a graphics object functions but I don't know the best way to proceed.

If you have any advises...

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Do you have experience with writing GUI's programatically?

Comment: Yes I do have some experiences...I am thinking about do it one by one for each channel. 12 channels in total. thus if I want to change something I have to change it 12 times. A mess.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is formulated quite generally, so depending on the details there might be more solutions to it. However, quite a general approach is the following one:

Assuming you have a function `plotSingleChannel` that gets as an input the channel data and the position available to it on the GUI, you can call it in a for-loop as many times as there are channels. A toy example is that, you'll need to tweak it to your needs (for example, maybe open more then one figure to handle many channels):

```
function plotManyChannels
fgui = figure;
numChannels = 5;
chData = rand (numChannels , 1000); % 5 random channels
chHeight = .8 * 1/numChannels; % occupy 80% of the available space, in order to leave some free inter-channel margins

for n = 1 : numChannels
    pos = [.05, 1 - n / numChannels, .9, chHeight];
    plotSingleChannel (chData(n,:), fgui, pos);
end
end

function plotSingleChannel (channelData, figHandle, guiPosition)
figure(figHandle)
buttonWidth = .1;
buttonPosition = [1-buttonWidth,guiPosition(2),buttonWidth,guiPosition(4)];
axHandle = axes ('position', guiPosition - [0 0 buttonWidth 0]);
plot(axHandle, channelData);
btnHandle = uicontrol('parent',figHandle,'style','pushbutton','string','push','units','normalized','position',buttonPosition);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very useful but I can't make any button next to the plots. Could you show me an example.

Comment: See my edited code for an example of adding a button to the right of each channel. I really recommend you try and edit my code and read the documentation for creating GUI programatically, you'll benefit from it much more then me giving you the code 'on a plate'.